# how to re-name alias in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I just started learning pig and I have a problem with re-naming an alias. Want I want to do is read a file, filter it, and then join it by itself. What I did is this:

```
register s3n://uw-cse-344-oregon.aws.amazon.com/myudfs.jar
raw = LOAD 's3n://uw-cse-344-oregon.aws.amazon.com/cse344-test-file' USING TextLoader as (line:chararray);
ntriples = foreach raw generate FLATTEN(myudfs.RDFSplit3(line)) as (subject:chararray,predicate:chararray,object:chararray);

ntriples2 = foreach raw generate FLATTEN(myudfs.RDFSplit3(line)) as (subject2:chararray,predicate2:chararray,object2:chararray);
X = FILTER ntriples BY (subject matches '.*business.*');
X2 = FILTER ntriples2 BY (subject2 matches '.*business.*');
joined= join X by subject, X2 by subject2;
joined = DISTINCT joined;
store joined into '/user/hadoop/join-results' using PigStorage();
```

as you can see I read and filter the file twice in order two have two different alias for each column. How can I simply copy the filtered collection and assign it new aliases? This operation was supposed to take 18 mins, but took 1.5 hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
X = FILTER ntriples BY (subject matches '.*rdfabout\\.com.*') PARALLEL 50;
y = foreach X generate subject as subject2, predicate as predicate2, object as object2 PARALLEL 50;
```

This is how you make copy of x and changing the aliases.